# docker engine installation error

Tags: software-installation, docker

I am new to Ubuntu and trying to install docker on Ubuntu 15.04 by following this [link](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/).

I have tried many times but always get the same error:

```
docker-engine : Depends: libdevmapper1.02.1 (>= 2:1.02.99) but  
2:1.02.90-2ubuntu1 is to be installed   
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `lsb_release -a` and the output of `apt-cache policy docker-engine libdevmapper1.02.1`

Comment: And please the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`

Answer (score 2):

You have Vivid installed, and the necessary package with the required version (2:1.02.99) is in Wily. Therefore use the Vivid version of docker. Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list` via

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
```

and replace the content with

```
deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-vivid main
```

then update the package database

```
sudo apt-get update
```

---

It's also **possible** to install the packages in Vivid

```
cd
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lvm2/dmsetup_1.02.99-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lvm2/libdevmapper1.02.1_1.02.99-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i dmsetup_1.02.99-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb libdevmapper1.02.1_1.02.99-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

If you have problems with the packages, downgrade via

```
sudo apt-get install libdevmapper1.02.1=2:1.02.90-2ubuntu1 dmsetup=2:1.02.90-2ubuntu1
```

---

Tested in my Vivid system

```
% apt-cache policy libdevmapper1.02.1 
libdevmapper1.02.1:
  Installed: 2:1.02.99-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2:1.02.99-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2:1.02.99-1ubuntu1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:1.02.90-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main i386 Packages
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the docker-engine completely from your system.

```
 apt-get remove docker-engine
```

Follow the below setups.
To check your current kernel version, open a terminal and use uname -r to display your kernel version:

```
 $ uname -r
```

3.11.0-15-generic
Install the recommended package.

```
 $ sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)
```

Update your APT package index.

```
 $ sudo apt-get update
```

Install Docker.

```
 $ sudo apt-get install docker-engine
```

Start the docker daemon.

```
  $ sudo service docker start
```

Verify docker is installed correctly.

```
 $ sudo docker run hello-world
```

For 15.04 and up, to configure the docker daemon to start on boot, run

```
 $ sudo systemctl enable docker
```

http://gotechnies.com/install-docker-engine-ubuntu/

Answer (score -1):

I tried a combination of all the other answers and finally what solved my problem was

```
sudo apt-get install docker.io
```